# SDL Web 8 - WebApp VisitorsWeb Needed to Publish

Tags: web8, installation

While following the QuickStart instructions [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-D1A69CDD-A7B0-452B-99BD-F01150102D90) I am not sure if I am required to setup the "visitor's .Net website" to make publishing with Topology Manager work.

So far I have successfully setup the CME, Discovery Service and Deployer Service (as Windows Services) using the PowerShell scripts.  All on the backend is working fine.  However, I want to be able to Publish, and is not clear what is absolutely necessary to be able to do that.

I see in the steps to setup TopologyManager that the last step involves the URL of the 'VisitorsWeb' site.  Is this required to make publishing work?  And, is this why it is mentioned to do it before the TopMan setup?

Comment: It is not needed, it's just a logical flow to follow if you're trying the end-to-end, rather than jumping between back and front-end

Comment: I was first looking forward to getting the content published to the Broker DB and the Filesystem (Pages), and then after that get the staging website working...

Comment: Have you created the Business Process Type, ? If not then create the Business Process Type,under the publication from where you want to publish your components and pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to publish using Topology Manager, you will need to have a BPT defined and selected in CM and Mappings for each Target Type (Purpose) defined in Topology Manager (Topology Manager Mappings are quite similar to Publication Targets in the old publishing model).

TTM Mappings define an association between a Publication, a Purpose and a Web Application.

A Web Application is part of a Website and a Website has a Base URL (or several).

So: in order to define a Mapping (and be able to publish) you will need to define a Website (and pretty much everything else in TTM).
The actual Base URL of the Website doesn't matter for publishing, so you could specify a bogus value, but you will need a proper value quickly after publishing anyways.